# mobile menu - to appear straightaway when on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

On mobile the sticky menu will slowly appear after the user scrolls past the first section: 
that was done as below:

```
         var $logo = jQuery('#header-sticky-wrapper');
            jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()> 250)
            {   //alert("scop");
         //  $logo.css({display: $(this).scrollTop() > 100? "block":"none"});
             jQuery('#header-sticky-wrapper').fadeIn( "slow" );
            }else{
                 jQuery('#header-sticky-wrapper').slideUp();
            }

        });
```

But now I want it to appear straight away on the top when users are using mobile devices. So it will be on the top of the first section on first load and then sticky.

Comment: Why don't use css position: fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position fixed and set top and left to 0.